# How can I get Doubles from a string after a specific key word?

Tags: java

I tried many ways. this is the one I gave up on

```
    double prevClose = 0;

    String test = "this is a test test test stop 123 3.5";
    Scanner parse = new Scanner(test);
    while(parse.hasNext()) {
        if(parse.next("stop") == "stop")
            prevClose = parse.nextDouble();
    }

    return prevClose;
```

Comment: Please.. not again.. compare Strings with `.equals`

Comment: Well, to start with `parse.next("stop") == "stop"` isn't how `String` comparison works in Java. You could use `String#subString` and `String#indexOf`, you could use regular expression...

Comment: @MarounMaroun My day on Stackoverflow starts with a String compare question.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ My day ends with it.

Comment: The rest of the day is filled with it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Have to propose stringcompare.stackoverlow.com on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) :P

Comment: You need to take a look at [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and forgive us, but we see this type of problem all the time. It's an easy mistake for the inexperienced to make...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the link. I'm running into another problem using the skip() method in the Scanner class. In a string I have a lone colon and want the double after it (in this test case its a string.) Using the skip() method from the Scanner class; why doesn't this work

    public String test() {
  String test = "why is this not : working";
  Scanner parse = new Scanner(test);
  
  while(parse.hasNext()) {
   if(parse.next().equals("not")) {
    parse.skip(":");
    test = parse.next();
   }
  }
  return test;
    }

Comment: @user3884880 I don't know why, but `parse.skip(" : ");` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compare Strings with equals.
2. Remove this `next("stop")` an call `next()` without parameters.

   ```
   double prevClose = 0;

   String test = "this is a test test test stop 123 3.5";
   Scanner parse = new Scanner(test);
   while(parse.hasNext()) {
       if(parse.next().equals("stop"))
           prevClose = parse.nextDouble();
   }

   System.out.println(prevClose);
   ```

   output: `123.0`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(parse.next("stop") == "stop")
```

Above will never give you true. So `prevClose` will always be 0. Always do String comparisons with `.equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` and not `==` opearator.

You can do the following

```
 while(parse.hasNext()) {
      if(parse.next().equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
      prevClose = parse.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's ignore the `String == String` problem in your code to start with and go a different direction...

Basically, all you want is all the text AFTER `stop`, for this we can use a combination of `String#indexOf` and `String#substring`

```
String test = "this is a test test test stop 123 3.5";
test = test.substring(test.indexOf("stop") + "stop".length()).trim();
```

Once you have the text you want, you can simply `split` the remaining text on the `" "` delimiter and you should have all the numbers in an array...

```
String parts[] = test.split(" ");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Which outputs...

```
123
3.5
```

For the `String` compare problem, you should take a look at [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more details

Comment: OP is actually facing this issue other than that compare issue +1.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ This is just intended as an example of another way to attack the problem, not saying it's the best, just different (and I have a personal dislike of `Scanner` ;))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
double prevClose = 0;

String test = "this is a test test test stop 123 3.5";
String[] split = test.split("stop");
String rightArray = split[1];
String[] numbers = rightArray.split(" ");
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    prevClose = Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]);
    System.out.println(prevClose);
}
```

**Output :**

```
123.0
3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only in String comparison but also another issues there.

```
    double prevClose = 0;
    String test = "this is a test test test stop 123 3.5";
    Scanner parse = new Scanner(test);
    while (parse.hasNext()) {
        if ("stop".equals(parse.next())) { // String comparison and next()
            prevClose = parse.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prevClose);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
while(parse.hasNext()) {
    if(parse.next().equals("stop")) {
        prevClose = parse.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Difference between `==` and `equals` - Since the String class override `equals` method, It return true if two String object contains same content but `==` will only return true if two references are pointing to same object.

Moreover `Scanner#next()`-Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.It does not accepts argument

Comment: Okay, but why and what additional value does this add that the other answers haven't already done...?

Comment: My bad but no one tried to explain the difference between `==` and `equals` and why he should use `equals` in his case

Comment: The first two answers did, explain the problem and the solution, at least as far as I can see, I even mentioned it my own answer, which avoided the problem entirely...

Answer (score 0):

```
    double prevClose = 0;

    String test = "this is a test test test stop 123 3.5";
   String[] test2 = test.split(" ");
   int i = 0;
    while(test2.length>i) {
        String string = test2[i];
        try {
            prevClose = Double.parseDouble(string);
            System.out.println(prevClose);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //System.out.println("this is not number");
            //do nothing
        }

        i++;
    }
```

Ouptput :

```
123.0
3.5
```

This will work for any type of string independent of **"stop"**